# A limit on leaflet layers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've been troubleshooting this issue with my code and have ran out of ideas. I have a map with multiple choropleth layers and everything was working flawlessly until I added the `opi_layer`. Within this variable contains line  `L.geoJson(opiData);` and I quickly found out that this line was causing my map not to load.

**Troubleshooting steps**

1. I thought maybe I added the javascript variable wrong in the file but I did not, even have the semi-colon at the end.
2. Then I was thinking the file was corrupt somehow. To test this I replaced `opiData` with `fenData` since I knew `fenData` was working. Wow and it worked! So this had me convinced the file was corrupt or something.
3. To test this theory I ran the data through a python script to spit out a geojson file just like all the other geojson files that are working. Still not working!
4. I still wasn't convinced nothing was wrong with the file so I copied fenData (was working with the map), changed the variable inside the file to fenData2 and renamed the file fendata2. NOPE!! To my suprise I'm still receiving a blank grey screen. Which means the file isn't corrupt.

My only other thought is leaflet doesn't allow more than three layers? I find this hard to believe.

The code is below.

```
var total_layer =
//ADDS GEOJSON DATA TO MAP
L.geoJson(totalData) 

//SETS CHOROPLETH COLORS TO MAP colorbrewer2.org
function getColor_blue(d) {
    return d > 489  ? '#084594' :
        d > 408  ? '#2171b5' :
        d > 326  ? '#4292c6' :
        d > 245  ? '#6baed6' :
        d > 163  ? '#9ecae1' :
        d > 82   ? '#c6dbef' :
                    '#eff3ff';
}

//APPLYS COLOR TO MAP BASED OFF SELECTED PROPERTY IN GEOSJON
function style_total(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor_blue(feature.properties.rate),
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
;

var herion_layer =
//ADDS GEOJSON DATA TO MAP
L.geoJson(herData) 

//SETS CHOROPLETH COLORS TO MAP colorbrewer2.org
function getColor_red(d) {
    return d > 472  ? '#99000d' :
        d > 394  ? '#cb181d' :
        d > 315  ? '#ef3b2c' :
        d > 236  ? '#fb6a4a' :
        d > 157  ? '#fc9272' :
        d > 79   ? '#fcbba1' :
                    '#fee5d9';
}

//APPLYS COLOR TO MAP BASED OFF SELECTED PROPERTY IN GEOSJON
function style_her(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor_red(feature.properties.rate),
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
;

var fen_layer =
//ADDS GEOJSON DATA TO MAP
L.geoJson(fenData) 

//SETS CHOROPLETH COLORS TO MAP colorbrewer2.org
function getColor_green(d) {
    return d > 18  ? '#005824' :
        d > 15  ? '#238b45' :
        d > 12  ? '#41ae76' :
        d > 9  ? '#66c2a4' :
        d > 6  ? '#99d8c9' :
        d > 3   ? '#ccece6' :
                    '#edf8fb';
}

//APPLYS COLOR TO MAP BASED OFF SELECTED PROPERTY IN GEOSJON
function style_fen(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor_green(feature.properties.rate),
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
    };
}
;

var opi_layer =
//ADDS GEOJSON DATA TO MAP
L.geoJson(opiData);

//SETS CHOROPLETH COLORS TO MAP colorbrewer2.org
function getColor_purple(d) {
    return d > 24  ? '#4a1486' :
        d > 20  ? '#6a51a3' :
        d > 16  ? '#807dba' :
        d > 12  ? '#9e9ac8' :
        d > 8  ? '#bcbddc' :
        d > 4   ? '#dadaeb' :
                    '#f2f0f7';
}

//APPLYS COLOR TO MAP BASED OFF SELECTED PROPERTY IN GEOSJON
function style_opi(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor_purple(feature.properties.rate),
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
    };
}
;

//SETS MAP STARTING LOCATION
var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [41.05, -77.5],
    zoom: 8,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
    layers: [total_layer],
});

//CREATES TILE LAYER
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: ""
}).addTo(map);

var baseMaps = {
    "Total": total_layer,
    "Herion": herion_layer,
    "Fentanyl": fen_layer,
    "Opium": opi_layer,
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);

//STYLES DATA FROM GEOJSON AND APPLYS THE LAYER TO MAP
L.geoJson(totalData, {
    style: style_total,
    }).addTo(total_layer);

L.geoJson(herData, {
    style: style_her,
    }).addTo(herion_layer);

L.geoJson(fenData, {
    style: style_fen,
    }).addTo(fen_layer);

L.geoJson(opiData, {
    style: style_opi,
    }).addTo(opi_layer)
```

Comment: There is no maximum amount of layers for leaflet, please reference: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/55499

Comment: How do you load your GeoJSON data? Also adding a sample data that reproduces the issue would tremendously help.

Comment: @ghybs I'm an idiot. As soon as i saw your first question I knew what was wrong. I didn't insert <script>"opiData.js"</script> in the html Doh! I'm new to javascript incase you couldn't tell